# medialibrary in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have developed an app for windows phone in windows phone 7.Everything is fine in windows phone 7.

But when i upgraded it for windows phone 8,I found that the listbox of images is not showing in a  page.After debugging

I found that media library is returning null,thats why listbox of images not showing any images

After searching over internet I found that for accessing media library images we have to first open windows phone's native photo app(native pictures).So I did it ,windows phone  8 emulator.Now it is working,but every time I have to open this native photo app,then I have to open my app,then only its working..Actually I dont have windows phone device,I just installed windows phone 8 sdk and tested it..

So my question is,Is there any way to directly access the media library with out opening native photo app,so that user dont have to open his native app every time before opening my app

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry, that problem won't affect Windows Phone 8 devices, it only concerns the emulator.

Comment: thanks for replying ,but it is effecting,I have developed software ,it is working in windows phone 7 devices but not working in windows 8 devices(media library returning null).You can download software gImage,and can test it for both windows phone device 7 and 8 devices..

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I access media library's album and pictures:

https://multiphotochooser.codeplex.com/

You could check on the source code to know how to achieve your goal.